# How to play videos and manage URLs seamlessly in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, video-player

Basically, in my Flutter application, I am creating video player functionality. For that, I am using the [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) and [chewie](https://pub.dev/packages/chewie) packages. However, as per the requirement, I want to play the video seamlessly. For example, if a user sets the video quality to 144k and starts playing a video, then after one minute, they decide to change the quality to 360k. In this scenario, I need the video to play from the same time where the user changed the quality.

To achieve this, I am using different URLs for videos of different qualities. When the user changes the quality selection, I use the corresponding URL for that selection. However, it takes some time to load and play the video from the exact time where the user clicked on changing the video quality selection.